# How do we import Products in Salesforce for professional edition

Tags: data, professional-edition

Could you please help me with how do we import Products in Salesforce for professional edition

Comment: Looked at Data Loader and Wizard, realised it does not support

Comment: To those putting the question on hold, I disagree - it is actually a good question. The asker wants to import Products into Salesforce Professional Edition. It's a simple question, but not too broad.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is the Excel Connector, which has a PE-compatible version. It uses an old API version, so you can't hit every new feature, but it will allow importing of your product catalog, pricebooks, etc.

Comment: Can we do upsert using Excel Connector?

Comment: No. You can export, update using VLOOKUP, and then update to Salesforce.

Comment: As far as I know it's only supported on Windows though...